# Choosing a Enum Class based on user input

Tags: java, enums

I have a package with a list of enum classes 
[image: Enum class package structure]

I want to be able to select a particular Enum class based on user selection in a constructor of a different class. 
Since one can not create instance of enums by using new operator in Java because constructor of Enum is private, is there any way around to choose a particular enum class?
Basically I want to do someting like this.

```
 public class A{
           Enum e;
           A(Enum e){
               e=new abcEnum();
            }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302376/how-to-set-the-value-of-an-enum-by-user-input

Comment: Start off with all you enums should implement one common interface.

Comment: @MouseEvent Thanks . I will try that and post back.

Comment: @MouseEvent I created a base interface. how do i point the base interface instance to a particular enum class?